# c# WPF Print (+ design printed document) in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We are developing a WPF application via the MVVM pattern for our internal users.
At the moment we are printing and designing documents via RDLC reports.
Now, personally, I'm not really a big fan of this approach. Specially not in the context of MVVM.
So I'm trying to find a new (better) way to handle this.

After some research I could already find 2 potential solutions, but I wonder if I'm going the right way.

- FlowDocument : I just have some trouble finding a decent example that uses the MVVM pattern
- SSRS

Are there any other solutions that would be better? The ultimate goals is to have a straightforward way to design and print a document with respect to the MVVVM pattern.
Any "real-life" examples would be nice. :-)
The biggest pain with the RDLC reports is building the datasets to feed the report.

The solution doesn't have to be free. :-) We can spend some budget if it's a good solution.

Kind Regards
Tim

Comment: Wouldn't the model class be perfect to work as dataset for your RDLC report? Alternatively, you may also consider Crystal Report for Visual Studio (Free since you don't profit from selling your reports), it select data from database and you update the selection (where clause) when generate (like SSRS). It support JavaScript based preview and can output to many formats.

Comment: Isn't RDLC going to go away in the (near) future? We've also been looking into Telerik Reporting. We already use their WPF controls.

Comment: Do you have any support document about RDLC will end soon? The extension still work with latest IDE (VS2019) : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001. Sorry can't help you on Telerik Reporting as I've never tried it, Crystal / RDLC never failed me so far.

Comment: As far as I know, the support for .NET Core is not that great. Unless they fixed it already. :-) Just a question, is using Word or Excel templates for document printing still a good solution? I've used that way int the past. But it's been years since I had the need for printing from desktop apps.

Comment: That's true about the the .NET Core situation, RDLC phasing out could be a matter of time I guess. I tried tools like PHPExcel and OpenXML for template report a few times. My experience is that they are good, easy to design and really fast for simple reports, but the complexity increase exponentially compare to report engines when you want more features like adding dynamic QRCodes / Images or data presentation with grouping, repeat header and etc. between pages.